# Salesforce added debug log on opening SFDC Console

Tags: developer-console, debug-logs

I am debugging a test class which is reaching debug log size limit.So I added a filter debug log for me which logs system.Error only. However, whenever I running a class from DevConsole, Salesforce adds DEVELOPER_LOG for my user entity which is not filtered and it overwrites the filtered log for me. Salesforce ignores filter debug log for me, as I have another debug log and create logs to all the information. It seems if a user has two logs level registered , SFDC pick which is less filtered and create log

Answer (score 1):

> Salesforce provides following 3 Log Types:

- **DEVELOPER_LOG** - When you open the Developer Console, it sets a DEVELOPER_LOG trace flag to log your activities.
- **USER_DEBUG** -  USER_DEBUG trace flags cause logging of an individual user’s activities
- **CLASS_TRACING** -  CLASS_TRACING trace flags override logging levels for Apex classes and triggers, but don’t generate logs.

Refer [Set Trace Flag Durations and Reuse Debug Levels Across Trace Flags](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_debugging_logging.htm) release notes

You can customize Developer_Log for your purpose just you have done for User_Debug.

Refer: [Customize Your Trace Flags and Debug Levels in the Developer Console](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_developer_console_logging.htm)

Comment: if I change the Developer log Salesforce added, then it changes for all developers. I don't want that. Is there a way to stop developer_log if user debugs added or stop overwriting userDebug

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change your DebugLevel that is associated with the current TraceFlag for your user.

[image]

Assuming the DebugLevel is unique to you this will only affect your current user.

See also:

- [Salesforce Debug logs with the Winter '16 Developer Console](http://www.fishofprey.com/2015/10/salesforce-debug-logs-with-winter-16.html)